# How can I search multiple value fields in a view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm fairly new to Drupal, but not to CMSs or PHP, so if I need to do this in code I will. It just seems it should already be possible with Views.

So, I'm making a view, and I want a 'combine fields' search filter for all fields. I can add my normal fields, but I don't seem to be able to add any field with "Display all values in the same row" checked under 'MULTIPLE FIELD SETTINGS'. This column simply does not show up in the options for the combine fields filter.

Any ideas? Might this be a solved problem? I can't be the only one...

Cheers,

J.R.